# Validate attachment file size in carrierwave with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, validation, carrierwave

I have carrierwave with mongoid and I want validate atachment file size.

I take a look to:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size

**but this fix it does not works for me.**

I have paste my code in the end from https://gist.github.com/1009861

**Please how validate atachment file size in carrierwave with mongoid?
Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is current rails version not autoloading lib/ directory anymore.

In your config/application.rb insert a line

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

to load modules in your lib/ (and it's subdirectories).
I'm using size check the way in the example, so pretty sure you can easily fix this issue.